# How can i reload a picture with Tkinter after GPIO button press?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have the following script based on a solution of another Stackoverflow question. I have a tkinter GUI with a picture that should refresh when there is taken a new one.

```
class App(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.start()

    def callback(self):
        self.root.quit()

    def run(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("{0}x{1}+0+0".format(800,800))

        files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()),key=os.path.getmtime)

        Label(self.root,image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(files[-1]).resize((300, 200)))).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        Label(self.root, text=files[-1]).grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.root.mainloop()

    def update(self):

        files = sorted(os.listdir(os.getcwd()),key=os.path.getmtime)

        img1 = self.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.Image.open(files[-1]).resize((300, 200)))
        Label(self.root,image = img1).grid(row = 1, column = 0)

        Label(self.root, text=files[-1]).grid(row=0, column=0)

        self.root.update()

app = App()        
app.update()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 176, in paste
    tk.call("PyImagingPhoto", self.__photo, block.id)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name "PyImagingPhoto"

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mainloop.py", line 98, in <module>
    app.update()
  File "./mainloop.py", line 79, in update
    img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(files[-1]).resize((300, 200)))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.paste(image)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/ImageTk.py", line 182, in paste
    _imagingtk.tkinit(tk.interpaddr(), 1)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C ssize_t
```

What am i doing wrong? Creating a label with with the file name does work. The filename is a valid file. The script does work when it is not inside the thread.Threading part. I would like to update the screen with the newest picture when a Raspberry GPIO button is pressed (script will take a new photo with a camara). So the screen should load with the lastest taken picture.

Answer (score 0):

tkinter is **not** thread-safe (by default). All operations dealing with the GUI must be done in the main thread. You can do what you are asking using callbacks on events, but threading can and will break tkinter unless you implement an event queue that feeds into the mainloop.

Additionally, the stack trace seems to point to not your code here- that stack trace doesn't intersect with the presented code at all.

Also, calling root.update() is generally a bad idea- it starts another local event loop, which may be able to call another root.update() for another event loop ad infinium. root.update_idletasks() is much safer than a full root.update()